# The most accelerated javascript snow

Tags: javascript, android, mobile-safari, hardware-acceleration

I have saw a lot of them, but all they look not accelerated and slow.

For instance:

- http://www.schillmania.com/temp/snowstorm/
- http://sebleedelisle.com/demos/JSSnow/snow3d.html

Is it possible at all to have a script that will be smooth enough on iPhone 4 / typical Android device (like Kindle Fire)?

Regards,

**UPDATE**

Thanks to Julian D.! designshack.net/?p=27674 is awesome! No scripts at all, pure CSS, several layers are moving in different directions. Some tips:

- Layer's patterns should be small enough (<=300px),
- There should be NO color animation (remove it from -webkit 50% and 100% keyframes),
- Use 2 layers instead of 3,
- Add -webkit-transform: translateZ(0); for all keyframes, see [HTML5 transition perfomance on iPhone 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7806514/html5-transition-perfomance-on-iphone-4/8979092#8979092) for details, thanks to mikeyUX.
- 20s is too smoothly, use 10s.

With all these tips it's fast enough on iOS (iPod 4 Touch) to be used in a real project.

Comment: you want the snow that is lightest and smoothest of them all ? so it can run on weak devices ?

Comment: I will be happy if it's possible at all. But that can be proved by referencing an implementation, so, yes, I'd like to see something that is fast enough on iPhone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are talking about hardware accelerated animations you want to look at CSS Keyframe Animation-based solutions, e.g.

- http://designshack.net/?p=27674
- http://natbat.net/code/clientside/css/snowflakes/

Here is a tutorial how to do 
- http://girliemac.com/blog/2009/02/18/using-keyframes-webkit-css-animation-examples/

Still, your mileage may vary. Some Android devices/version don't support hardwarde acceleration at all, you are out of luck here.

Comment: http://designshack.net/?p=27674 is awesome! No scripts at all, pure CSS, several layers are moving in different directions. Some tips: layer's patterns should be small enough (<=300px), there should be NO color animation (remove it from -webkit 50% and 100% keyframes), use 2 layers instead of 3, add -webkit-transform: translateZ(0); for all keyframes, 20s is too smoothly, use 10s. With all these tips it's fast enough to be used in a real project.